# Changing text color of menu heading title item in navigation drawer

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement dark mode in my application. I've implemented on menu item. It is changing the color but what I want is to change the color of heading as well because when dark mode is implemented the heading menu is hidden as the color is light grey.

Navigation Menu:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="?attr/bgColor"
    app:itemTextColor="?attr/textColor"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />
```

[image: Light Theme]

[image: Dark Theme]

Comment: Do you want to change the heading color or the menu item texts?

Comment: I want to change the heading color

Comment: yes I've updated my answer with tested code, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>` inside your `AppTheme` and `AppTheme.NoActionBar` styles.xml file like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
...
</resources>
```

where the color value `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` is placed in `colors.xml`.

The result looks exactly like you wanted:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but it changes the color of the item but I want to change the color of the heading/title like **favourite** in the first pic. @SaadAAkash

Comment: @UmarSaleem, oh yes I understood your requirement. Please follow the edited answer code and let me know if it works.